# SwiftUI: How do I open the (App-)phone settings when I push a Button?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I´m new in SwiftUI. I want to know how can I open the App Settings in the Setting App from the iPhone, when the user push a Button in the App.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open phone settings when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: No that's in Swift, but I need something in SwiftUI

Comment: SwiftUI is only a Swift framework. What you write in SwiftUI Button's `action` is pure Swift.

Comment: Ahh Okay thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422905/11671205), you can use the following sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.settingsOpener()} ){
            Text("Open Settings")
            
        }
    }
    
    private func settingsOpener(){
        if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```